# Geopandas spatial join returning no rows

Tags: python, geospatial, geojson, geopandas

I am trying to do a spatial join of my geodataframe, where each row is a visitor

My GeoJSON is here

```
import geopandas as gpd
geo_json = gpd.read_file('http://geoportal1-ons.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/01fd6b2d7600446d8af768005992f76a_0.geojson?outSR={%22latestWkid%22:27700,%22wkid%22:27700}')
```

A geometry looks like this - it's not co-ordinates

MULTIPOLYGON (((398583.804 653093.703, 398601....

The crs looks like this

```
<Geographic 2D CRS: EPSG:4326>
Name: WGS 84
Axis Info [ellipsoidal]:
- Lat[north]: Geodetic latitude (degree)
- Lon[east]: Geodetic longitude (degree)
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

A co-ordinate in my visitors data look like this
POINT (-2.64185 53.55189)

If I run the spatial join, and keep the same crs as the geo json, I get no rows

```
customers = pd.DataFrame({'visitor':[1],'geometry':[Point(0.26371,51.15565)]})
customers_geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame(customers,
crs = geo_json.crs,
geometry = customers.geometry)

customers_geo.head()

spatial_join = gpd.sjoin(geo_json, customers_geo, op = 'contains')

spatial_join
```

Why is this happening? If I use other GeoJSON I get rows

Comment: That crs is a result of `geo_json.crs`? If yes, then it is likely wrong because coordinates are in projected CRS, not geographical.

Comment: yes that's `geo_json.crs`. what should i do, contact the geojson provider? can i not fix it myself?

Comment: You have to figure out what is the actual CRS of the file and manually assign it `geo_json.crs = something`. You may fix it yourself if you can guess the crs correctly.

Comment: I used the shapefile instead, and it's worked! thanks for your help